# i have a problem with using #define it stops at zero

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define IC 60  
#define TAX_PERCENTAGE 7.5

int main()
{

    float tax_decimal = TAX_PERCENTAGE / 100;
    float ST = IC * tax_decimal;
    float total = IC + ST;
    printf("Price = %f\nTax = %f\nTotal = %f\n\n",IC, ST,total);

}
```

this is my code

why does #define TAX_PERCENTAGE stop at zero? because 7.5 / 100 = 0.075 but it just stops at 0. is it because #define is an int?

how do i fix this?

thanks

Comment: the question is unclear. There is a clear error in printf where you expect a float as first argument (%f) but pass an int (IC). But you are asking about TAX_PERC?

Comment: `warning C4477: 'printf' : format string '%f' requires an argument of type 'double', but variadic argument 1 has type 'int` Once that is fixed it's fine: https://ideone.com/O1fNwj Defines have no type. They are literal text replacement, so how the compiler would interpret that text in context becomes their type.

Comment: `#define TAX_PERCENTAGE 7.5f` (optional) and `printf("Price = %d ...` If you have concern about an integer divisor, add a trailing `'.'`, e.g. `TAX_PERCENTAGE / 100.;`(also optional, but explicitly shows intent)

Comment: @AdhamZahran - that's not really a problem. It may look like a problem, but the `#define TAX_PERCENTAGE 7.5` creates a floating-point constant. Thus in `TAX_PERCENTAGE / 100;` the terms will be promoted to `float` and the calculation will be correct. Adding `'.'` after `100.` makes the intent clear.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thanks for your help and the detailed explanation

Comment: what if i changed the TAX_PERCENTAGE TO 7? it becomes an int

Comment: I have rolled back the edit. Please do not make substantial changes to a question after it has already been answered, because then the answers do not make sense. Instead, you can accept an answer and post a new question.

Answer (score 2):

`IC` expands to `60`, which is an `int`. Your `printf` specifier expects a `float`. If you fix that, it should work fine:

```
#define IC 60.f  
#define TAX_PERCENTAGE 7.5f
```

Answer (score 2):

As others have pointed out, the problem is not in the macros or the arithmetic but in the call to `printf`, but it might look a bit odd that you can get completely garbled output if the calculations are right.

When I run

```c
printf("Price = %f\nTax = %f\nTotal = %f\n\n", IC, ST, total);
```

for example, I get

```
Price = 4.500000
Tax = 64.500000
Total = 0.000000
```

while with the correct

```c
printf("Price = %d\nTax = %f\nTotal = %f\n\n", IC, ST, total);
```

I get

```
Price = 60
Tax = 4.500000
Total = 64.500000
```

The thing is, `printf` doesn't know about the type of its arguments except through the formatting string. It has no way of knowing, as we don't track type information anywhere in C. So, `printf` has to parse the formatting string and then interpret the arguments it got as having the corresponding types. If the formatting string is wrong, `printf` will interpret its arguments wrong, and what happens is anyone's guess.

The `IC` macro defines a literal integer, so if you want to print it, you must use `%d` (or cast to another appropriate type). If you use `%f`, then `printf` will interpret its arguments as having a float parameter and get the data from wherever it gets its data on your platform.

Where a function gets its argument depends on the platform, but it is not unusual that integers and pointers go in some registers, floats in others, and such. If I am calling `printf("...", i, f, f)` with an integer and two floats, the integer might go in one register as the "first integer argument" and the two floats somewhere else. But if I told `printf` via the formatting string that I had given it three floating-point arguments, it would look where it expects floats to be, and if that isn't where the integer went, it just won't see the integer argument. Instead, it will see the two floats I gave it and some garbage where it expected a float to be.

Variadic functions are tricky that way. A call that seems totally fine will go wrong if the caller and receiver do not agree on what the arguments are.

For `printf`, though, compilers generally know how to check if the formatting string and the arguments match. If you turn on warnings, it should catch it here as well.

Comment: thanks for the answer but what if i changed the TAX_PERCENTAGE to 7 it becomes an int

Comment: Yes. If you want the macro numbers to be floats, write 7.0f or cast them (float)7. You could also use `static const float IC = 60` or some such. The important point is that the formatting string and the type of the arguments must match.

Answer (score 1):

Use `%d` for displaying `IC` value In print because you assigned integer value to `IC`.

Use this code it will help.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define IC 60  
#define TAX_PERCENTAGE 7.5
int main()
{

    float tax_decimal = TAX_PERCENTAGE / 100;
    float ST = IC * tax_decimal;
    float total = IC + ST;
    printf("Price = %d\nTax = %f\nTotal = %f\n\n",IC, ST,total);
   return(0);
}
```