# Trouble printing out a #define

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
# define IC 60
# define TAX_PERCENTAGE 7

int main()
{
    float tax_decimal = TAX_PERCENTAGE / 100;
    float ST = IC * tax_decimal;
    float total = IC + ST;
    printf("Price = %d\nTax = %f\nTotal = %f\n",IC, ST,total);
}
```

don't mind the title

when i tried to run the program, it wont print out the ST and why is that?

can anyone help find out what's wrong with it?

thanks

Comment: `TAX_PERCENTAGE / 100` -> `TAX_PERCENTAGE / 100.0`

Comment: Printing out intermediate results (like `tax_decimal`) to verify your assumptions is a time-proven debugging strategy. ;-) You'd be looking at "why is 7 / 100 == 0?", and with a bit of luck have found the problem on your own. ;-)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [i have a problem with using #define it stops at zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70000717/i-have-a-problem-with-using-define-it-stops-at-zero)

Answer (score 2):

The expression `TAX_PERCENTAGE / 100`, or equivalently `7 / 100`, is performing integer division.  This means that the result will be truncated to an integer.

To perform floating point division, at least one operand must have a floating point type.

```
# define TAX_PERCENTAGE 7.0
```

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Doh!  That one didn't need to change, so removed.

Answer (score 0):

it's a integer division `float tax_decimal = TAX_PERCENTAGE / 100;` use float division `float tax_decimal = TAX_PERCENTAGE / 100.0;`